# Did they remove SendFileAsync in DSharpPlus?

Tags: c#, discord

My bot was able to send people a random image a year or maybe 2 ago but now I can't seem to get it work anymore as apparently when I use the 'ctx' to access its channel to send a file, the SendFileAsync method doesn't exist anymore. When I try it the way below, the bot does send a message with a title but the image doesn't come through...

```
   `[Command("random")]
    [Description("displays a random image.")]
    public async Task Yiff(CommandContext ctx)
    {
        var random = Directory.GetFiles(_basePath);
        if (!random.Any())
        {
            await ctx.RespondAsync("No files found.");
            return;
        }
        var rnd = new Random();
        var nmbr = rnd.Next(0, random.Length);
        var file = random[nmbr];
        await using var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        var channel = ctx.Channel;
        await ctx.RespondAsync(embed: new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
        {
            Title = $"Random img for {ctx.User.Username}",
            ImageUrl = $"attachment://{fileName}",
            Color = DiscordColor.Blue
        }.Build());
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked [the documentation](https://dsharpplus.github.io/DSharpPlus/index.html), and I didn't see any references to a `SendFileAsync()` method. However, it does look like you are inserting a custom string in the URL property of the `embed` object you are building. I would imagine you need to be inserting a valid URL instead. You could test this by pasting in any image URL to see if that image appears in the messages you are sending.

Comment: I have tried a random gif from Giphy and that seemed to work but I want to be able or atleast know how to send and image from a local source.

Comment: You likely can't. The client sending the photo needs to have access to the image. If the image you are trying to send is stored on your local machine, it would need to access your local directory to retrieve it. This would require some non-trivial steps regarding port-forwarding to enable, which might not even be possible with the bot's functionality. You could try uploading your photos to a online directory that syncs with your local files (OneDrive for example).